# Undertanding OOP and static methods

Tags: python, oop, static-methods, self

I haven't coded in OOP ever before.  I've some functions to handle and verify VAT numbers and I want to enclose them in a class (more later, with other classes for handle IBAN account numbers make a module or a package, I'm not sure yet what's the difference of both).

I take a VAT number (CIF in spanish terms) and, at first, I need to clean it from any other characters than digits and letters.  Then validate the number.

Input:

```
h55/586-75 4
```

Desired Output:

```
H55586754
True
```

Real Output:

```
h55/586-75 4
False
```

My Code:

```
import re

class CheckingCIF:

    _letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSVW"    # Not used yet.

    def __init__(self, un_cif):
        self.cif = un_cif
        self._limpiarCIF()

    def _limpiarCIF(self):
        self.cif = re.sub('\W', "", self.cif.upper())
        return self

    def validarCodigoCIF(self):
        if len(self.cif) != 9:
            return False
        numero = self.cif[1:10]
        pares = int(numero[1]) + int(numero[3]) + int(numero[5])
        impares = 0
        for i in range(0, 8, 2):
            j = int(numero[i]) * 2
            if j < 10:
                impares += j
            else:
                impares += j - 9
        digito = str(pares+impares)[-1]
        if int(digito) == 0:
            checkCIF = 0
        else:
            checkCIF = 10 - int(digito)
        if str(checkCIF) == self.cif[-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    entradaCodigoCIF = input('Enter the VAT number: ')
    mi_cif = CheckingCIF(entradaCodigoCIF)
    print(mi_cif.cif)
    print(CheckingCIF.validarCodigoCIF(mi_cif))
```

The problem isn't in the validarCodigoCIF(self) method, since I've test before and it works fine.

The issue probably is in the _limpiarCIF(self) method because my incomprehension of the Object Oriented Programming and the use of the `self` word and the static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have static methods, you have regular methods, but are not calling them *on the instance*:

```
entradaCodigoCIF = input('Enter the VAT number: ')
mi_cif = CheckingCIF(entradaCodigoCIF)
print(mi_cif.cif)
print(mi_cif.validarCodigoCIF())
```

Referencing the method on an instance gives you a *bound method*, an object that knows how to call the underlying function and pass in the instance as a first argument.

Comment: `_limpiarCIF(self)` isn't a static method?

Comment: No, in Python, `staticmethod` is a decorator that causes *just the function* to be returned, e.g. unbound, with no automatic `self` parameter. It essentially gives you a function that can be reached from the class and instance but is not bound to either. I suspect you are applying the term *static* from a different programming language here.